# Is there a name for someone that accepts a risk and then complains when it occurs?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, terminology

Example:

Frank is going to buy a house

The real estate developer, Jim, warns him, there's a 30% chance your house will drop a lot in value in the next year.

Frank buys the house.

The value of his house drops a lot in the next year.

Frank tries to sue Jim.

You would call Frank a...

Comment: A bad investor?

Comment: An Opportunist?

Comment: How about 'human'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might somewhat metaphorically call such a person a *[sore loser](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sore_loser)*.

Though there's no actual game being played in your example, there's a similar dynamic; someone accepts the rules of the game but isn't willing to accept the results when things turn out badly.

There's also the concept of *[buyer's remorse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buyer%27s_remorse)*, but that's specific to regretting a purchase, while your question seems to be asking for a more general term.

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using these two adjectives

> **reckless** — heedless of danger or the consequences of one’s actions; rash or impetuous
>
> **devil-may-care** — cheerful and reckless

---

[Oxford Dictionaries reference](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reckless?q=reckless)

Comment: I'd say that definitely covers someone that accepts the risk. It's more the complaining about the bad outcome after the fact that I'm looking for. Thanks!